# Cordova build for Windows Mobile 8.1 is not compatible with Windows Mobile 10

Tags: cordova, windows-mobile

I try to release a cordova/ionic app for Windows Devices (like Lumia 550). This is one of the devices which runs "Windows 10 Mobile" - according to wikipedia.

The config.xml file of the project contains the following windows related entries:

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
```

I understand those entries as lowest version so that windows 10 should be included. The app is available on windows mobile 8.1, windows 8.1 and windows 10.

When I try to install the app on a windows mobile 10 device, it is not possible due to the store saying that the app is not compatible with the device.

The app is configured to be available to "[windows 10 family devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZVvM.png)".

According to [this blog entry from microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/07/29/targeting-windows-10-with-your-apache-cordova-app/), it should work for windows 10. When I set windows 10 as build target, the app is not available anymore for windows 8.1. Is there any way to release one app for 8.1 and 10 (especially for mobile devices)?

Is there anything I could have missed? Does Cordova support "windows 10 mobile"? I have spent a lot of time searching for proper answers and all that I found was

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but you have to do the following according to the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/#project-configuration):

To target Windows 10, set `windows-target-version` to `10.0` in `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

This is not the lowest supported version, think of it as the highest.

If you want to build the app for another version, use the `--appx` parameter:

```
cordova build windows -- --appx=8.1-phone
```

If you want to **deploy** the app for another version, again use the `--appx` parameter:

```
cordova run windows --appx=8.1-phone [...]
```

Not tested if this works though...